# Does an AC wave running through a wire produce EM waves?

Tags: rf, electromagnetism

I understand that current from a DC source running through a wire produces a magnetic field. However, is the changing magnetic field produced via current from an AC source, technically a part of a EM or radio wave?

If so, do transmission lines produce EM waves at 50-60 Hz?

Comment: Yes, think of how a speaker works.

Comment: Yep. That's why a lot of stuff has 50-60Hz filtering built-in by default.

Comment: In steady-state solutions to EM, the math shows 1/R, 1/R^2, 1/R^3 terms. The books then show how the 1/R term is initially very weak (because of scalefactor), but becomes dominant at about 1/2 wavelength. Note that "dominant" does not mean the other terms have become zero. You can read about this as "near field" maths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, an AC current in a wire emits electromagnetic (EM) radiation.

How efficiently it emits depends on how long it is. If it's a tiny fraction of a wavelength long, then it's very inefficient at emitting propagating, far-field, EM radiation. Most of the energy stays as near-field, non-propagating magnetic fields.

The business of crafting a wire so it emits EM efficiently is called antenna design.

Comment: Does the EM oscillate at the same frequency as the AC?

Comment: Yes, it couldn't do so at some other frequency

Comment: Expert question : what is the antenna efficiency for harvesting grid  outside wire  energy with a 100m  wire  parallel to the power line. Imagine outside there are  50kV 3phase lines nearby and your wire is just above the ground just to 1 significant figure.  what impedance will give MPT?

Answer (score 0):

The grid  is also is a “transmission line” and it produces 50-60 Hz waves so phases must be matched between shared generators to achieve the right power factor or V/I phase. But the wavelength only factors into very long trunks not your measurements in a short wire.

The E field is in V/m and can be capacitively coupled by any open wire scope probe with your finger on 10M. Adjacent wire pairs can be 1pF/cm.

So yes , even AC power gives off EM radiation and is easily detected touching a 10:1 probe with your finger. But very low power into 10Meg.  Then when you also touch the ground lead, it drops to 0. Your body is a capacitor and your finger tip is an electrode.  Can you measure the finger tip ESR*C with this method.? By varying finger pressure and surface area? If not why not?

The B field is current in A/m or uA/m and is coupled. The mutual inductance coupling into your high impedance ground/signal area loop is converted to a voltage. adjacent wire pairs can be 0.5 to 1uH/m but mutual coupling is inversely related to gap and area. As we view these as either **plane sources, line sources or point sources** depending on distance away the attenuation is respectively, **uniform, 1/r, 1/r^2  path loss**

Both of these indicated you either want a low impedance sensor if on a long cable (50 Ohm)  and/or a very well balanced signal and return path to cancel as well as possible this CM (Common model coupling , so it cancels. **This is another method of EM reduction.**

### Questions to test your understanding

We can say your body dielectric makes a good antenna for hum and TV signals , yet AC 50,60 HZ is a very long wavelength, so how can it go right thru us without sensation thru the air?

What is the current into a 10 M probe? At say 50V from your finger.

How does touching ground shunt this high impedance EM field?

Expert question: if you know free space impedance is low impedance , why does this not carry high AC current thru air. Hint it has to do with antenna gap to wavelength ratio of efficiency and impedance. Explain in your own words.